# Importing Objects into a Visual Studio 2010 Server Project

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to reverse engineer my database via the SQL Server Wizard in the VS2010 database project template. I'm able to RE my database, but it's not enough, because in order for my sprocs to compile without errors and warnings, I need to have my linked servers and their logins included also. However, my DBA's can't give me the required VIEW ALL DEFINITION permission on the SQL Server in order to run that wizard at the server level. They don't want to do that for me in VS2010 so I am stuck. Has anyone had success compiling or found a work around for using the database level database project and using linked servers and other server level objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developers can create an empty server project. You can then have your DBAs populate it via "Import Database Scripts and Objects" command. Just have them right-click the server project and they'll see that as the top command.

Your database project then should add a reference to this server project, and you should be all set.

Microsoft designed database projects on the assumption that only a DBA will import objects. For instance, in importing a SQL Server 2008 database, if you don't have "VIEW DEFINITIONS" privilege, you'll get an error about attempting to import user encryption keys. You'll get this error even if there are no user encryption keys! They assume only a DBA will do that.

---

Read and vote on [Schema Compare permission error for Database Encryption Keys even though the type is set to be ignored](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552986/schema-compare-permission-error-for-database-encryption-keys-even-though-the-type-is-set-to-be-ignored) if you would like to let Microsoft know what you think about this issue.

Comment: Thanks John, I'll give that a try! Do my DBA's need access to my empty server project, or can they just send me the scripts and objects?

Comment: They need access. In fact, they may eventually decide to maintain database settings and objects using the server project. They're the only ones who should have write access to that project.

Comment: Shoot, that's my problem. They don't use VS2010 nor do they want to. They don't source control their servers. I just wanted to get it RE'd one time so I could get the project setup for my source control and have it compile without thinking objects are missing. So, I either need to get those permissions myself or have my DBA's adopt VS2010 database server projects? Or, is there some way to have VS2010 ignore the missing objects errors when compiling?

Comment: You can ignore some, but you don't want to. They don't have to adopt database projects - they only need to do that import once, and can log into your machine to do so. They can even use your VS2010, as long as they use SQL Server credentials to connect to the db.

Comment: Is it possible to: 1) Create a server project, 2) RE my database as a database project 3) import those objects into my server project using "Add Existing Item 4) have dba script the server from SSMS 5) import in the object I needs from that SSMS script? Or am I going to run into all sorts of configuration issues the Wizard would have solved for me? I'm wondering how the server project knows which database the tables go into... are they represented by a Schema in the server project? I probably shouldn't try to look at it like I see it in SSMS!

Comment: No, sorry, I don't think that scripting the server with SSMS will script everything that the database project wants. You can try, but I expect it will miss things. There's an impedance mismatch there.

Comment: A server project is for server-level objects and settings only.

Comment: Hi John, so I shouldn't be using the server project to develop multiple databases on that server. If I want to do that, I should have a server project for server objects, then database projects for the individual databases?

Comment: That's correct. Server projects for server-level objects and settings, database projects for database-level objects and settings. Multiple databases reside on one server, which is why multiple database projects can reference the same server project.

Comment: My DBA is says she won't script items that I don't have rights to. Can she give me a .dbschema without me actually being able to see the structure? A .dbschema is like a .dll in a way right, where my project can compile and see certain things (like object properties), but I can't see how it's built.

Comment: You would have to create the server project in a separate solution. The DBA's should populate the project and the project should be built. You would not have access to the project, but they would have to send you the .dbschema file. You could use that in the server reference.

Comment: Awesome, that's the way I'm going to go. Thanks so much John :)